# Does tire load index count bike weight and rider weight?

Tags: tires

I have some questions around tire load index (LI). On this matter, motorcycle tire.

1. Is the load index count the vehicle weight and rider weight (and pillion and/or any other weight such as bag) ? So for example, rear tire with LI 66 (300kg). Bike wet weight is around 170kg. Rider and pillion weight is 140kg. Total 310kg. What would happen to the rear tire ? Since all the weight exceed the tire LI ?

Or perhaps, the LI is combined for front and rear tire. For example, front LI is 58. Rear LI is 66. Tire LI combined is 236(58)+300(66)= 536kg. So the bike tires have maximum weight capacity around 536kg. Which is way above the 310kg carrying weight.

2. What about the front tire LI ? Does it count the braking weight force ? Or even stoppie weight ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The tires share the **total** weight of the bike unequally...